# Limit notation question

Tags: limits, notation

lim(d^2 --> infty) d - 1 = infty
Is this valid notation, or must it be written using lim(d --> infty) instead? I would like to express that as d^2 tends to infinity, d - 1 tends to infinity as well. Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: It sounds to me then, like you are saying $\lim_{d \rightarrow \infty} (\sqrt{d} - 1) = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that $d-1
$ is a function of $d^2$. Why sould it be $\sqrt{d^2}-1$ and not $-\sqrt{d^2}-1$?

For the first one, you get the limit $\infty$ and for the second one, $-\infty$.

You should probably change your notation.

Answer (score 1):

You can write 
$$\lim_{d\to\pm\infty} d-1=\infty$$
or more accurate
$$\lim_{d\to\pm\infty} d-1=\pm\infty$$
or if you want
$$\lim_{d^2\to\infty} d-1=\infty$$